# Microsoft Graph API Receiving ErrorInvalidRecipients while using the me/messages/<id>/send endpoint

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

We are seeing many `ErrorInvalidRecipients` error codes being returned when using the `me/messages/<id>/send` microsoft graph api endpoint, causing emails to permanently remain unsent and in the Drafts folder. We have confirmed that these items in question all have a recipient filled out in the `to` field. The perplexing piece of this is that when a user manually sends the email from the Outlook Desktop Client, the email is sent without any issues.

How does Microsoft validate the email when using this endpoint and what can we do to mitigate this on our end so emails always go out? We ideally continue to use the send endpoint. Here is the flow from the user's perspective:

1. User installs our Outlook Add-in
2. User composes an email draft via the Outlook Desktop Client (adds recipients / subject / body / etc)
3. User clicks a button added to the desktop client through our Add-in
4. Our system finds the item by its id.
5. Our system processes & alters the html body of the email
6. Our system saves the item
7. Our system uses the `me/messages/<id>/send` endpoint to deliver the message

This is the response returned from the graph client:

```
{
  code:"ErrorInvalidRecipients",
  message: "At least one recipient is not valid., Recipient 'xxx@example.com' is not resolved. All recipients must be resolved before a message can be submitted.",
}
```

In this scenario, `xxx@example.com` is the only recipient on the item. When the user manually sends this email via the Outlook Desktop client, the email sends and delivers without any problems.

Expected Behavior:
using the `me/messages/<id>/send` delivers the email when a valid address is attached to the item by the user from the Outlook Desktop Client

Actual Behavior:
an `ErrorInvalidRecipients` is returned

I am struggling to find documentation on this error code all i can find is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxwsmtgs/409af410-de5f-42e3-9f24-2295a8c72f5d) which unfortunately is just as vague as the error I am receiving.

I also dont even know how to reproduce the error. When I try to enter an intentionally invalid email address I see what I expect. The email is sent and I then receive in my inbox a message from outlook saying the item failed to deliver.